# I need help in designing a circuit to connect an Arduino MEGA and a CD-Pickup Reader/Writer

Tags: arduino-mega

I'm trying to use the IR source and detector of the CD Pickup reader/writer (KSS-213C) along with the lens focussing/tracking system. I want to control them using an Arduino MEGA. So since I will be needing one constant source for the diode, I will connect it separately to a source, not to the Arduino. Since this is a sensitive device, I read that you need to have constant current sources and so on. Now, I'm new to designing circuits of my own, I found this picture in an article, but it is for a DVD writer. Could someone tell me if I could use the same circuit with some modifications or should I try something else. Now note that my main output is that of the IR sensor that my Arduino would read. [image]

Comment: I don't know how to answer most of your question, but one caution. The relay in that circuit should either be a "digital" relay that's separately powered and designed to be controlled with a CMOS logic signal, or you need to drive it using a power transistor protected with a "flyback diode". (Inductive loads like relay coils have "back EMF" that will destroy solid state components like transistors or Arduinos.)

Comment: @DuncanC, there was a circuit given in the question of this link: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/278887/how-to-determine-the-operating-voltage-and-current-of-a-laser-diode. Can I use the same instead of the LM317-Constant Current Source circuit from my question?
By the way, I'm sorry I don't know if my relay is a digital one. I'm using a HE-LQC3FC Relay, would that work?